# Ionic 3 Google Map does not display on Desktop Browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been trying to display google maps on my local browser but the screen seems to be empty.

I feel like the map is loading at the backend but not being displayed.

I could see the map cursor pointer.

In my code, `index.html` file, I have  referred to the `maps api`

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCToBv6QzLZWTuqHa7aPeHn6KCCy-nuwKk"></script>
```

Also, in my `.html` file,

```
<ion-content>
    <div #map id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

And `.ts` file, the codebase looks like :

```
declare var google;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})
export class MapPage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapRef : ElementRef;

  map : any;

  game : any;

  currentTournamentData : any;

  location : any;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams,
    private eliteApi : EliteApi,private platform : Platform) {
    this.showMap();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.game = this.navParams.data;
    this.currentTournamentData = this.eliteApi.getCurrentTournamentData();
    this.location = this.currentTournamentData.locations[this.game.locationId];
  }

  showMap() {   
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);
        var mapOptions  = {
            center : latLng,
            zoom : 15,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    });
  }

}
```

There is no error on the console but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: Try `this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, mapOptions);`

Comment: Tried, no luck :( @hrdkisback

Comment: @StrugglingCoder, Can you please edit question again with new code changed

Comment: Try to put this method `this.showMap();` call in `constructor` .

Comment: @PareshGami Have changed it. Please see.

Comment: @hrdkisback If I put, `this.showMap()` call in constructor, it says, `cannot access nativeElement of undefined`.

Comment: <div #map id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px";></div>

Can you please that. i think double quote is issue

Comment: @PareshGami That was just a typo. It is actually with quotes. Please see updates.

Comment: Change google api url like below  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<api-key-goes-here>"></script>

Comment: @StrugglingCoder, 1). put your `showMap();` method's logic in this line `this.platform.ready().then(() => { // Your showMap() method's logic here });` 2). Also you need to import `Platform` from `ionic-angular` 3). Call this method `this.showMap();` from `constructor`.

Comment: @PareshGami Tried the same no luck.

Comment: @hrdkisback Followed your instructions.. still, map is on the blank screen.

Comment: Any error on `console`?

Comment: @hrdkisback No error :( That's the weird part. I feel map is being loaded just that it is not visible.

Comment: Then i think issue is in your ` <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` as @Presh suggested try to change google api link with your generated `key`

Comment: @I tried it. But still no luck . Please see the edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162018/discussion-between-hrdkisback-and-strugglingcoder).

Comment: @hrdkisback Hey found it. Finally nailed it. It works fine just that you have to remove `@IonicPage()` attribute, basically I tried with blank template. Found it. Thanks.

Comment: @PareshGami  Hey found it. Finally nailed it. It works fine just that you have to remove `@IonicPage()` attribute, basically I tried with blank template. Found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with the blank template and found out what's causing the issue. Remove `@IonicPage()` and it works flawlessly. 
Sometimes it is better to start with the slate clean.